# Properties of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on the following two questions:

**My first question:**

If $D$ is a non-singular matrix, such that $(D+D^*)$ is positive definite. From my understanding of the problem's solution, it says that $D$ has to be positive definite. Why is this true?

**My second question:**

If $A$ and $B$  are positive definite matrices, why is : $A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ positive definite? Now the other way: if $A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ positive definite and $A$ is positive definite, does this imply that $B$ is positive definite?

Comment: For the first question, the spectral theorem gives that $D+D^*$ is at least positive semi-definite.  For the second, if all the eigenvalues of $B$ are positive, the same is true for any similar matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first question: not true. Take
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

On the second question: again not true . Take 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\ 1&3\end{bmatrix};
$$
Then $A^{1/2}BA^{-1/2}$ is not even symmetric.

Comment: You don't need symmetric to be positive definite (which is just that all the eigenvalues are positive).

Comment: @Martin Argerami: I must have misunderstood the problem's solution. Anyway, I will post the problem and the solution as it is written in the book in a new topic, and I can tell you where I am stuck.

Comment: @Aaron: I must have misunderstood the problem's solution. Anyway, I will post the problem and the solution as it is written in the book in a new topic, and I can tell you where I am stuck

Comment: @Aaron: I know that symmetric or not is a contentious issue on the definition of positive definite. Now, according to your "definition", $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 100&1\end{bmatrix}$$ is positive definite. I cannot agree with that.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: The square matrix $A$ represents the bilinear form $(x,y)_A=x^TAy$, and  while symmetric bilinear forms are nice, there are other forms worth considering.  Positive definite should mean that $(x,x)_A\geq 0$ for all $x$, with equality if and only if $x=0$.  However, you are right that my "definition" was an oversimplification of the issue.